# JavaScript and HTML assignment

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, I'm ashamed to be asking, but it just isn't clicking. My brother-in-law has an assignment to have a text box and then a command button. When the button is pressed, it will loop 10 times printing whatever was in the text box. Should be simple - I know!

I know the error is on this line:

```
<input type="button" value="Press Here" onClick="sayit(document.getElementById('myTextField').value) ">
```

Here's what we have:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Homework #11 part 2 </title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sayIt(var message){

        count = 1;
        num = 10;
        while (count <= num) {
        document.write(message);    
            document.write("<br/>");

            count = count + 1;
        }


}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
Type in a phrase.
<input type='text' id='myText' />


<br />
<input type="button" value="Press Here" onClick="sayit(document.getElementById('myTextField').value) ">

</p>
</body>
```

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title> Homework #11 part 2 </title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sayIt(var message){

        count = 1;
        num = 10;
        while (count <= num) {
  document.write(message); 
            document.write("<br/>");

            count = count + 1;
        }


}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
Type in a phrase.
<input type='text' id='myText' />


<br />
<input type="button" value="Press Here" onClick="sayit(document.getElementById('myTextField').value) ">

</p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Where is the "myTextField" element in the page?

Comment: use a for loop for that if its for school... for (i=0; i < 10; i++){document.write(message)}

Answer (score 5):

The code has three thins wrong.

1) `function sayIt(var message)` should be `function sayIt(message)`
2)`onClick="sayit(....)"` should be `onClick="sayIt(....)"`

sayIt is function name

3)`document.getElementById('myTextField').value` should be `document.getElementById('myText')`

myText is input element's id attribute

Answer (score 4):

You've got three things wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/jcfD8/

<sup><sub><sup><sub>Hints - you don't need var in your function declaration, your id is not right, and you "misspelled" sayIt</sub></sup></sub></sup>

( ^ If you care to see the answers, they are above ^ )

Invest in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). It gave me all the answers I needed. ;)